# How to JUnit Test Jersey when Services are deployed in Server?

Tags: java, junit, jersey, jetty

I have written a Jersey service which I have deployed in Jetty server. Here is a sample:

```
@Path("/simple-on-off")
public class SimpleOnOffService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get-state")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getCurrentState(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {        
        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
}
```

If this service is deployed in the Jetty server then I can see my IP address in the browser by following the URL: localhost:8080/rpi/service/simple-on-off/get-state

My question is how can I perform JUnit Test by accessing this service? Any pointer would be very helpful.

Comment: That's not clear. Just start Jetty instance before unit testing  and in the unit tests hit the desired URL. In general this is not the way You should go. Google for `jersey test framework` or `jersey test grizzly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using some testing frameworks such as: Jersey Test Framework or REST-Assured (https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured). I personally like a lot REST-Assured. See my answer in another question here: [Unit testing jersey Restful Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413738/unit-testing-jersey-restful-services/21425393#21425393)