# How to run jetty server for java junit testing

Tags: java, rest, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to write an integration test to spin up jetty server locally and then use client to communicate with the rest URI and call the business logic downstream. However, when I start my jetty server it does not relinquish the control, so my client is not executed. So I used threading to start my jetty in a different thread, however, the thread finishes before my client call, it says connection refused. Any approach I can take?

```
@Test
public void testPerform() {

    final JettyServer jettyServer = JettyServer.create();
    jettyServer.buildJettyServer(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS, "/", 8080, TestResource.class);

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            jettyServer.start();
        }
    };

    new Thread(runnable).start();

    final javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    final Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/test").request().post(Entity.text(""));

    jettyServer.stop();
}
```

Comment: What class is `JettyServer`? there is no method `buildJettyServer` in the [Jetty documentation](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/)

Comment: I am implemented a final class JettyServer which uses org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server to spin up jetty server.

Comment: Sure, but the not knowing what that class does makes it more difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Ohh. I thought that would not matter in this case, as the server works as expected when I spin it up and hit it from the browser. The only problem was the junit test. I am sorry for that.

Comment: Perhaps, but we didn't know that.

Comment: Alternatively, you might bet better off using [JerseyTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413738/unit-testing-jersey-restful-services).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Skip the `Runnable`, skip the `new Thread(runnable).start()`

The call `jettyServer.start()` starts the server on its own thread (along with all of the other threads that the server needs.

For a basic example of junit and jetty ...

```java
@Test
public void testGet() throws Exception
{
    // Create Server
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
    ServletHolder defaultServ = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
    defaultServ.setInitParameter("resourceBase",System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    defaultServ.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
    context.addServlet(defaultServ,"/");
    server.setHandler(context);

    // Start Server
    server.start();

    // Test GET
    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://localhost:8080/").openConnection();
    http.connect();
    assertThat("Response Code", http.getResponseCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK_200));

    // Stop Server
    server.stop();
}
```

The `@Before` and `@After` junit annotations can also be used.  This will start the server before each `@Test` and stop the server after.

```java
package jetty;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpStatus;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JUnitBeforeAfterJettyTest
{
    private Server server;

    @Before
    public void startJetty() throws Exception
    {
        // Create Server
        server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        ServletHolder defaultServ = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
        defaultServ.setInitParameter("resourceBase",System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        defaultServ.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
        context.addServlet(defaultServ,"/");
        server.setHandler(context);

        // Start Server
        server.start();
    }

    @After
    public void stopJetty()
    {
        try
        {
            server.stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() throws Exception
    {
        // Test GET
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://localhost:8080/").openConnection();
        http.connect();
        assertThat("Response Code", http.getResponseCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK_200));
    }
}
```

For the best approach, you can also use the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` techniques, along with auto-binding to an open port.  This will only start the server once, per Test Class, run all of the `@Test` methods, then stop the server once at the end.

```java
package jetty;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpStatus;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JUnitBeforeAfterClassJettyTest
{
    private static Server server;
    private static URI serverUri;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startJetty() throws Exception
    {
        // Create Server
        server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(0); // auto-bind to available port
        server.addConnector(connector);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        ServletHolder defaultServ = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
        defaultServ.setInitParameter("resourceBase",System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        defaultServ.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
        context.addServlet(defaultServ,"/");
        server.setHandler(context);

        // Start Server
        server.start();

        // Determine Base URI for Server
        String host = connector.getHost();
        if (host == null)
        {
            host = "localhost";
        }
        int port = connector.getLocalPort();
        serverUri = new URI(String.format("http://%s:%d/",host,port));
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void stopJetty()
    {
        try
        {
            server.stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() throws Exception
    {
        // Test GET
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) serverUri.resolve("/").toURL().openConnection();
        http.connect();
        assertThat("Response Code", http.getResponseCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK_200));
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked when I moved the implementation of my jetty server inside the junit test, as per your answer above.

Comment: That's not the only way, went ahead and added 2 more for you.

Comment: How do i get the serverUri when i have the server already running outside from junit?

Comment: @Gobliins since you don't have access to the ServerConnector in that setup, maybe you could use JMX to obtain the Server Connector configurations you need. (course, you'd need to start the Server with JMX enabled then)