# How to deploy a Java Web project with Jetty without building war

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, deployment, jetty

I have a Java Web project with Maven and using Eclipse and Jetty Eclipse plugin to run it.

I'm trying not to use Eclipse but I don't find the way to deploy the app with Jetty without using a WAR. With Jetty plugin it just take 1 minute to startup but WAR building with maven does 20 min aprox.

There's any way to quickly deploy the app (as fast as with the Eclipse plugin) without building a WAR file? There is not mandatory to use Jetty but desirable.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you tried [tag:embedded-jetty] in unit testing perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29759263/775715

Comment: I've tryied adding jetty-plugin in the pom and files manually because maven can't access to repository (IDK why), so i can execute "mvn jetty:run".