# impossible to send multipart/form-data

Tags: java, tomcat, post, servlets, jetty

I made an application which received 2 parts: a picture and some text. The start of the code is:

```
  @WebServlet("/App")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*10,    // 10 MB
        maxFileSize=1024*1024*50,       // 50 MB
        maxRequestSize=1024*1024*100)       // 100 MB
public class App extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 205242440643911308L;
    private static final String PREFIX = "stream2file";
    private static final String SUFFIX = ".tmp";

    private static final String UPLOAD_DIR = "uploads";

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,
                          HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        JsonObject servletResponse = new JsonObject();

        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println(req.getContentType());
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        String text = null;
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        File dbPropsFile = new File("/config.properties");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(dbPropsFile);
        props.load(fileReader);

        for (Part part : req.getParts()) {
            if(getFileType(part).equals("image")) {
```

The code fails on

```
for (Part part : req.getParts()) {
```

It works completely fine if I'm running it with `mvn jetty:run`, but when deployed to the server, it just crashes. Please help!!!

When trying to do `System.out.println(req.getContentType());` this comes as null on the Tomcat and on the Jetty server, but it comes with the expected value on the `mvn jetty:run`

Comment: What does your `WEB-INF/web.xml` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `HttpServletRequest.getContentType()` is null, then your request isn't satisfying the requirements for `@MultipartConfig` which requires the `Content-Type` value to be `multipart/form-data`

Ensure that your form is being submitted properly on the network first.

Perhaps [add some unit tests to your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758607/how-to-run-jetty-server-for-java-junit-testing/29759263#29759263) to ensure that the servlet is behaving as expected, allowing you to focus your attention on the form submit / request side.

Comment: It was an issue with the multipartconfig. Sorted now. Thanks a lot