# Alternatives to the Gradle Gretty Plugin

Tags: gradle, jetty, embedded-jetty, gretty

I’m trying to upgrade some old code that used the [Jetty plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/jetty_plugin.html) in Gradle. I would like to upgrade the Gradle version beyond Gradle v3.5, but Gradle v4.0 and above has the Jetty plugin removed. Unfortunately, we are now required to use [Gretty](https://gretty-gradle-plugin.github.io/gretty-doc/).

I’m using IntelliJ. My problems with the newer Gretty plugin are:

- JVM Args and System properties specified on the commandline have to be manually put into the Gretty configuration.
- At least in IntelliJ, I could do out of the box debugging with the Jetty plugin, but need to run two executions including the app and the Remote, and use a different Gradle task for debugging (e.g. jettyRunDebug) with Gretty.

  What are the alternatives to Gretty? Anything that can substitute for the old  Jetty plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just skipping the Gretty plugin entirely and just using Unit testing?

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29759263/775715

Comment: Thank you @Joakim-Erdfelt. Your suggestion certainly helps if one is using Jetty in the context of testing. Unfortunately, in my case I'm using it for development i.e. jettyRun, then once the server starts, I debug my code. While this may help others, it actually does not help me.

Comment: Many projects use embedded-jetty (which is what Gretty plugin, jetty-maven-plugin, Official jetty-home, and jetty-distribution are all build on) to start a running Jetty instance with whatever configuration that they want.  This includes webapps (war) files, and even complex multi-context war file groups.  Using junit (or testng) to kick start this process for development and debugging is exactly how these projects get things done without a reliance on the build tool.

Comment: Thank you @Joakim-Erdfelt. I guess that's a good suggestion to use embedded-jetty, but I have to do a bit more research on how to make it work in my particular project.