# How to mock GET HTTP request using JAVA

Tags: java, rest, mockito

How can I mock GET http request using JAVA?
I have this method:

```
public HTTPResult get(String url) throws Exception{
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
            return new HTTPResult(response.getBody(), response.getStatusCode().value());
        }
        catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
            String responseBody = e.getCause().getMessage();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            return new HTTPResult(obj.getString("responseBody"), Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("statusCode")));
        }
    }
```

How can i verify i am getting: responseBody - some json and statusCode for example 200?

Comment: Did you take a look at `MockMvc`?

Comment: I noticed that you didn't accept any answer yet. Please consider doing that at some point. Or let me know if you have any additional questions here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "true" unit test, you have to look into using a mocking framework, such as EasyMock, or Mockito (I recommend the later one). That *might* make it necessary to rework your production code, as calls to `new()` often make problems with these frameworks (there are other frameworks that are better there: JMockit, or PowerMockito, but again: if possible go with Mockito).

If you are rather asking for a more "end to end" kind of test: there are test frameworks for Jersey ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413738/unit-testing-jersey-restful-services) for example ). Meaning: you can actually "unit test" your REST endpoints almost completely, without the need of running a real server.