# Junit test cases for REST API

Tags: rest, api, testing, junit, jersey

I need to write a junit test case for REST API.Am new to Junit test case can anyone help me to understand and write the test cases for REST APIs with so many EJB injections.

1. Do i need to call the actual api end point while writing the test cases or can i mock a server to achieve the junit test cases for APIs.
2. junit test cases must display the code coverage, how can we achieve this.

Note: REST Application is **NOT** a spring based application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit testing jersey Restful Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413738/unit-testing-jersey-restful-services)

Comment: This is a very, very broad question. Are you asking for a verbal description of possible tests? Are you asking how to test a class like this with so many injections (through `@EJB` annotations)? Have even tried something that you can share here? Remember: People here want to help you with specific problems, not write your tests for you. So please be as precise as possible what you want to achieve, what you have tried and what you were not able to figure out yet.